# libclouderahiveodbc64.so file not found

Tags: hive, odbc, aix

I have problem using latest Cloudera Hive ODBC Driver 2.6.9 for 64-bit AIX 7.1. On Linux host such configuration works flawlessly

```
$ oslevel -s
7100-03-05-1524
$ getconf KERNEL_BITMODE
64
```

It seems that isql works itself but cannot load driver with following message "file not found"

```
$ ../bin/isql_64 -v "Cloudera Hive 64-bit" user pass
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/build/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so' : file not 
found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

UnixODBC as well as driver are 64-bit. Isql is working itself

```
$ file /build/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
/build/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
$ file ../bin/isql_64
../bin/isql_64: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module
$ ../bin/isql_64 --version
unixODBC 2.3.9
```

Library paths are set properly:

```
echo $LIBPATH
/build/lib
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/build/lib
```

Environment variables are pointing to my configs which also seem fine:

```
$ env | grep INI
CLOUDERAHIVEINI=/build/lib/cloudera.hiveodbc.ini
ODBCSYSINI=/build/etc
ODBCINI=/build/etc/odbc.ini
```

Driver is pointed correctly in *.ini files

```
$ cat /build/etc/odbc.ini  | grep Driver
Cloudera Hive 64-bit=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive 64-bit
Description=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit) DSN
# Driver: The location where the ODBC driver is installed to.
Driver=/build/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so

$ cat /build/etc/odbcinst.ini | grep Driver
[ODBC Drivers]
Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive 64-bit=Installed
[Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive 64-bit]
Description=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit)
Driver=/build/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
```

Neither do ldd or isql show missing dependencies

```
$ ldd libclouderahiveodbc64.so
libclouderahiveodbc64.so needs:
     /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libC.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libC.a(shr2_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libC.a(shr3_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libC.a(ansi_64.o)
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libC.a(shrcore_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libC.a(ansicore_64.o)
 $ ldd ../bin/isql_64
 ../bin/isql_64 needs:
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
     /build/lib/libreadline.a(libreadline.so.7)
     /build/lib/libodbc.a(libodbc.so.2)
     /build/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42.o)
     /build/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o)
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
```

Any tips kindly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You could try to debug with `truss` eg `truss 2>truss.log ../bin/isql_64 -v "Cloudera Hive 64-bit" user pass`

Comment: Thanks, already tried that, found nothing interesting. https://pastebin.com/ghEVXLT5

Comment: There is an unsuccessful `kload("/build/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so",0x1010280,"/opt/teradata/client/15.00/lib:/build/lib")` in it. Sadly, no details about the reason.

Comment: A note: Once in my youth I created a test-program that performs dlopen and writes detailed error-message if it fails, maybe you could try it: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0041

Comment: Thanks. Just what I suspected. Problem with libC.a https://pastebin.com/wbX4jurH . What is interesting on fresh install of AIX 7.2 driver works like a charm